# WPF Interactions CallMethodAction для DataTemplate в ListCheckBox ругается на входные параметры метода во ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

Пытаюсь воспользоваться механизмом поведения, однако не могу правильно прописать аргументы в методе во `ViewModel`. Использую `ListBox` состоящий из item включающих в себя `CheckBox`, собственно перепробовал разные комбинации входных параметров метода, но никак не могу получить объект `Item` из `ListBox` при снятии галочки у `CheckBox`.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox Name="PropertiesListBox"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding PropertiesItems}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPropertyItem}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                               <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction  MethodName="PropertyUnchecked"
                                        TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                   Text="{Binding Path=Item.FieldsProperty.Name}"
                                   Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                        <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                            <Path Width="20" 
                                  Height="20" 
                                  Stretch="Fill" 
                                  Fill="{DynamicResource CommonBorderButtonBorderMouseOnBrush}" 
                                  Data="{StaticResource NextBtnGeometry}" />
                        </Canvas>
                        <StackPanel/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**C#**

```
public void PropertyUnchecked()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unchecked");
}
```

в итоге получаю ошибку:

> Thrown: **"Could not find method named 'PropertyChecked' on object of
>   type 'CheckedListItem 1' that matches the expected
>   signature."**(System.ArgumentException)   Exception Message = "Could not
>   find method named 'PropertyChecked' on object of type
>   'CheckedListItem`1' that matches the expected signature.", Exception
>   Type = "System.ArgumentException", Exception WinRT Data = null

Исходя из сообщения, я посчитал, что метод в коде `ViewModel` не имеет нужных входных параметров (`CheckedListItem<TProperty`> именно такие итемы хранятся в `ListBox`), начал экспериментировать:

**[1]**

```
public void PropertyUnchecked(CheckedListItem<TProperty>tr, object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unchecked");
}
```

**[2]**

```
public void PropertyUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unchecked");
}
```

**[3]**

```
public void PropertyUnchecked(object sender)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unchecked");
}
```

Также поэкспериментировал с разметкой:

```
<CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Left"
          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="PropertyUnchecked"
                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName = "PropertiesListBox", Path = "DataContex"}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

С такой разметкой заработал пустой C# метод, а также [2] и [3], однако ничего кроме CheckBox и его свойств как элемента (в sender) мне не пришло, но нужен именно Item в котором сидит объект типа `CheckedListItem <TProperty\>`.
Нашел как реализовать нечто подобное командами с параметрами, но мне **нужен именно вызов метода**, и обойтись без команд.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я получил ответ на свой вопрос, звучит он так:
This is probably what you're looking for:

```
public void PropertyUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ((ContentPresenter)((CheckBox)e.Source).TemplatedParent).Content as CheckedListItem<TProperty>;
}
```

Собственно сам вопрос и ответы доступны по ссылке: [Вопрос и ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746290/wpf-interactions-callmethodaction-for-datatemplate-in-listcheckbox-thrown-a-exce)